# Accessing array element from API data

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

so maybe you've heard of Splinterlands.  This is from a bot that I'm trying to customize, but JS is so confusing to me.
When I display the array with JSON.stringify(teamToPlay), I get this:

```
{ 
  "summoner": "167",
  "cards": [167, 162, 192, "", "", "", "", "fire", "", ""]
}
```

I'm trying to pull out "fire", the 8th element in the cards array. "cards" is an array, right?
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain you with another example

```
const info = {
    firstName: "priyam",
    lastName: "shah",
    birthYear: 1000,
};
console.log(info.firstName);
console.log(info["lastName"]);
```

This is how you can access objects. Now it's quite easy to find the 8th character from the array right ? arrName[index]

So it should be `obj.cards[7]` assuming you save this data coming from api to a variable called obj.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  I should have realized it was 0-based.  I kept trying obj.cards[8].  Thanks a lot!